# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on ExpressionEngine® Answers breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          5
Users destroyed                                   1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            32         45
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         17         14
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               13          8
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                41        111
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                2          0
Questions protected                               0          1
Questions migrated                                3          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0         20
Questions closed                                  9          0
Question flags handled⁴                           7         13
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                   0          3
Posts locked                                      0          8
Posts deleted⁵                                   21        237
Posts bumped                                      0        141
Comments flagged                                  0        291
Comments deleted⁶                                73        228
Comment flags handled                            78        213
Answers flagged                                   0         58
Answer flags handled                             35         23
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of ExpressionEngine® Answers](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...